# PhpPgAdmin asks enter login and password

Tags: php, postgresql, phppgadmin

I installed PhpPgAdmin in CentOS.
Every time select an object (database, table, schema,..) PhpPgAdmin asks me to enter my login and password.

Left side menu (Servers->PostgreSQL) not connected.

**System**

- CentOS 5
- PHP Version 5.1.6
- PostgreSQL8.3.11

thank you,

G. Padmanabhan.

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: Yes. I could able to run 「PhpPgAdmin」from another server with same Environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem sounds like the session is lost. Possible problem sources:

- Browser does not accept cookies
- PHP cannot store session data because the session save path does not exist, is not writable or no space is left

Comment: According to php.ini, check the session_save_path. The directory should be writable by everyone.

Comment: I had the same problem, and it turned out there was no free disk space  left. The unix command "df -h" might help others to check for available disk space!

Comment: It was a disk space issue in my case too

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a permissions / ownership issue for the session save path for php.  This happened to me when I changed the User and Group in httpd.conf (apache) to a different username.  The php sessions files must have their group id's changed at the same time.  For Fedora, modify the group as below (substituting the group name of apache httpd):

```
sudo chgrp NEWUSER /var/lib/php/*
```

Restart httpd after making this change.

If this change does not work for your configuration, check your apache error logs (/var/log/httpd/error_log) for more information- they will give you the location of the session.save_path that needs your attention. For example:

> Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issues and found the problem I was having.
I have a limited user to a specific database.
If you open the other databases in the tree view and it says "Error Loading Database" then you don't have permission to those. It will then ask you every time you click on something to login to get access to those databases. Close them and it should be fine.